# Reusing SQLAlchemy models across projects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, code-reuse

I have some standard SQLAlchemy models that I reuse across projects. Something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Unicode
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    slug = Column(String(250), nullable=False, unique=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(250), nullable=False)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.title
```

I'd like to put this in a shared library and import it into each new project instead of cutting and pasting it, but I can't, because the `declarative_base` instance is defined separately in the project. If there's more than one, they won't share sessions. How do I work around this?

[Here's another question that suggests using mixin classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626787/sqlalchemy-avoiding-repetition-in-declarative-style-class-definition). Could that work? Will SQLAlchemy accurately import foreign keys from mixin classes?

Comment: What are you doing with the Base objects after this? Last I remember, I was able to merge together multiple metadata's from multiple Base objects by binding them all to the same engine. I would imagine that it would be enough to use a session from that engine to access all of the tables you've defined.

Comment: Nothing further with the Base object. If binding to metadata is all it takes, I could easily import and rebind -- while ensuring that two separate apps don't run in the same Python process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call

`Base = declarative_base()`

SA create new `metadata` for this `Base`.

To reuse your models you must bind `metadata` of main models to reusable models, but before any import of your reusable models by:

`Base.metadata = my_main_app.db.metadata`

MixIn classes useful for repeating column declarations, and extending class methods.
For `connecting` reusable apps based on MixIns you must define concrete class in code manualy for each model.

> Will SQLAlchemy accurately import
>   foreign keys from mixin classes?

MixIn class with foreign key and constraint

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

class MessageMixIn(object):
    ttime = Column(DateTime)

    @declared_attr
    def sometable_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sometable.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return (UniqueConstraint('sometable_id', 'ttime'), {})
```